# PHP: content from the database isn't displayed correctly

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

In database, field looks good, but when this field is shown in webapp, blank characters appears before content that I read from database. When I print content of query, this field is shown wihtout blank characters. Any suggestions to resolve this problem?

content on web app:
 http://postimg.org/image/bxz6k7yzz/

content in database: http://postimg.org/image/siix0jrdf/

Here I print content on in view.

```
                <div id="algcode">
                    <pre>
                      <code class="language-cpp">
                          <?php echo $query->content; ?>
                      </code>
                    </pre>
                </div>
```

In model:

```
         $query = $this->db->query($sql2);

         if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
         return $query->row();
         }
```

In controller:

```
          public function searchAlgorithm ($id) {
              $this->load->model('algorithm');
              $this->load->model('comment');

              $algorithm ['query'] = $this->algorithm->getAlgorithm($id);
              if($algorithm['query']!=false) {
                  $algorithm ['id'] = $this->algorithm->getId($id);
                  $algorithm ['comments'] = $this->comment->getComments($id);

                  $this->loadViews($algorithm);
              } else {
                  $this->loadErrorViews();
              }
          }
```

Comment: have you tried using `trim()` while echoing `$query->content` ?

Comment: I get FATAL ERROR:
Fatal error: Call to a member function trim() on a non-object

Comment: `trim();` is not really an object, so you are probably using it wrong

Comment: There is no need for trim as @goksiii has shown there to be no whitespace to trim from the DB. Instead the `<pre>` is including your white space and tabbing. See my answer below. That's what they're using on [codefleet](http://www.codefleet.net/prism-wp/) code formatter anyhows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use white space in your `<pre>` tag

You have:

```
<pre>
  <code class="language-cpp">
    <?php echo $query->content; ?>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Try this:

```
<pre><code class="language-cpp"><?php echo $query->content; ?></code></pre>
```

Or:

```
<pre><code class="language-cpp">
   <?php echo $query->content; ?>
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to mark your question as answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use trim this way:

```
     <div id="algcode">
                    <pre>
                      <code class="language-cpp">
                          <?php echo trim($query->content); ?>
                      </code>
                    </pre>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use whitespace in your `<code>` tag, and use trim, like this:

```
<code class="language-cpp"><?php echo trim($query->content); ?></code>
```